# Angular 12 getting error while defining BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular

Errors I Get:

```
Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IBasket'.
Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IBasketTotal'.
```

Service Code:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Basket, IBasket, IBasketItem, IBasketTotal } from '../share/models/basket';
import { Product } from '../share/models/product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BasketService {

  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  private basketSource = new BehaviorSubject<IBasket>(null);
  basket$ = this.basketSource.asObservable();

  private basketTotalSource = new BehaviorSubject<IBasketTotal>(null);
  basketTotal$ = this.basketTotalSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getBasket(id: string) {
    var x = this.http.get<IBasket>(this.baseUrl + "basket?basketId=" + id)
      .pipe(
        map(
          (basket: IBasket) => this.basketSource.next(basket)
        )
      )
    this.getCalculateBasket();
    return x;
  }

  setBasket(basket: IBasket) {
    return this.http.post<IBasket>(this.baseUrl + "basket", basket).subscribe(
      (response: IBasket) => {
        this.basketSource.next(response);
        this.getCalculateBasket();
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  getCurrentBasketValue() {
    return this.basketSource.value;
  }

  getCalculateBasket() {
    try {
      const basket: IBasket = this.getCurrentBasketValue();
      const shipping = 0;
      const subTotal = basket.items.reduce((a, b) => (b.price * b.qty) + a, 0);
      const total = shipping + subTotal;
      this.basketTotalSource.next({ shipping, subTotal, total });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  incrementItemQty(item: IBasketItem) {
    const basket: IBasket = this.getCurrentBasketValue();
    const foundIndex = basket.items.findIndex(x => x.id === item.id);
    basket.items[foundIndex].qty++;
    this.setBasket(basket);
  }

  decrementItemQty(item: IBasketItem) {
    const basket: IBasket = this.getCurrentBasketValue();
    const foundIndex = basket.items.findIndex(x => x.id === item.id);
    if (basket.items[foundIndex].qty > 1) {
      basket.items[foundIndex].qty--;
      this.setBasket(basket);
    }
    else {
      this.removeItemFromBasket(item);
    }
  }

  removeItemFromBasket(item: IBasketItem) {
    const basket: IBasket = this.getCurrentBasketValue();
    if (basket.items.some(x => x.id === item.id)) {
      basket.items = basket.items.filter(x => x.id !== item.id);
      if (basket.items.length > 0) {
        this.setBasket(basket);
      }
      else {
        this.deleteBasket(basket);
      }
    }
  }

  deleteBasket(basket: IBasket) {
    return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + "basket?basketId=" + basket.id).subscribe(() => {
      this.basketSource.next(null);
      this.basketTotalSource.next(null);
      localStorage.removeItem("basket_id");
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  addItemBasket(item: Product, qty: number = 1) {
    const itemToAdd: IBasketItem = this.mapProductItemToBasketItem(item, qty);
    const basket: IBasket = this.getCurrentBasketValue() ?? this.createBasket();
    basket.items = this.addOrUpdateItem(basket.items, itemToAdd, qty);
    this.setBasket(basket);
  }
  private addOrUpdateItem(items: IBasketItem[], itemToAdd: IBasketItem, qty: number): IBasketItem[] {
    console.log(itemToAdd);
    const index = items.findIndex(i => i.id === itemToAdd.id);
    if (index === -1) {
      itemToAdd.qty = qty;
      items.push(itemToAdd);
    }
    else {
      items[index].qty += qty;
    }
    return items;
  }

  private createBasket(): IBasket {
    const basket = new Basket();
    localStorage.setItem("basket_id", basket.id);
    return basket;
  }

  private mapProductItemToBasketItem(item: Product, qty: number): IBasketItem {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      name: item.name,
      price: item.price,
      qty: qty,
      pictureUrl: item.pictureUrl,
      brand: item.productBrand,
      type: item.productType
    };
  }
}
```

The code from which the error originates:

```
private basketSource = new BehaviorSubject<IBasket>(null);
private basketTotalSource = new BehaviorSubject<IBasketTotal>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

BehaviorSubject expects an initial value of the given type (IBasket / IBasketTotal).

If you don't want an initial value, just use a regular Subject.

You could also define the BehaviorSubject like this:

```js
new BehaviorSubject<IBasket | null>
```

...but I don't see why you would want to force a 'null' anywhere in your code.

You can consider BehaviorSubject to be the same as Subject piped through a 'startsWith':

```
subject.pipe(startWith("Your initial object goes here"))
```

Comment: I tried defining it like this but

Comment: I tried defining it like this but

 const basket: IBasket = this.getCurrentBasketValue();

The methods I use give the following error

Type 'IBasket | null' is not assignable to type 'IBasket'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'IBasket'.

Comment: Then first do a check if it is null, e.g.= if (yourObjectThatCouldBeNull) { // assign here } or make your const IBasket | null aswell, but again ... You should probably not propagate 'null' values in your code.

Comment: If you want the initial value to be null, just initialize the variable you are updating (using the Subject) to null where you declare it, and make that variable of type IBasket | null.